# Uploadify does not work on password protected sites

Tags: jquery, flash, .htaccess, uploadify

I use the JQuery plugin [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) for uploading files. It works fine in all browsers. If however I imlement a passwort protection via .htaccess like this

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile /my/path/to/.htpasswd
AuthPGAuthoritative Off
Require user dev
```

uploadify stops working in Firefox. In Chrome it still works.

In Firefox the file select box works, but after I selected a file the progress bar does stay at 0% and the file is not uploaded to the server.

I guess the issue is somewhere with flash on password protected sites. Any ideas how I can fix this, without removing the password protection?

Comment: Where do you implement the password protection. In the page that serves the Flash, or the script that Uploadify uses to send the file to?

Comment: Both I guess, for its located in the document root and is valid for the whole subdomain. Both Crome and FF ask me for the password once I press upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up excluding the uploadify directory from authentication (so everything is still password protected, except for the file upload).

To do so, I created a .htaccess file within the uploadify directroy with this lines:

```
allow from all
satisfy any
```

This article helped a lot:

http://brett.batie.com/software-development/password-protect-all-but-one-file-htaccess/

Answer (score 2):

There is a fairly well known flash bug that breaks authentication.

Read about it here (it's for swfupload, but I'm sure it applies to uploadify as well):

http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#knownissues (under 'Cookie Issue')

You'll probably have to pass session information from the upload page to the upload script.

Workarounds are posted on the swfupload site, but I can't seem to find them anymore.

They have a demo of the flash bug here: http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/cookiebugdemo/index.php